# How do you respond to tapping on a textfield only when you click up on Blackberry Cascades simulator in QML?

Tags: c++, qt, textfield, qml, blackberry-10

I am trying to figure out how to respond to the tapping on a textfield in Blackberry Cascades.  Right now, I have this sort of code:

```
TextField {
    onFocusedChanged: {
        if (focused) {
            doStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

But this responds the moment you click on an item, but doesn't wait till you let go of the mouse in the simulator (or the equivalent in a real blackberry)

Comment: If you want the code to be executed only on a click event (i.e. press and release), you could use 

    TextField{
    
        MouseArea {
          anchors.fill: parent
          onClicked: doStuff()
        }
    }

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot use MouseArea.  That causes this error: Cannot assign to non-existent default property
                    MouseArea {
                    ^) 
QmlDocument:createRootNode document is not loaded or has errors, can't create root

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, this worked for me in Simulator. I don't have a blackberry device to check this.

```
TextField {
    id: field
    width: parent.width

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked:{ console.debug("Got click event received! \nSetting focus for TextField");  field.focus = true; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, much appreciated, but MouseArea doesn't seem to be implemented in the version of QML I am using.  I am using Blackberry 10 Cascades, with the QNX Momentics IDE btw.

Comment: I hope MouseArea is a standard QML Element. Like int, float in c. So try this even if the IDE doesn't auto complete it show some error.

Comment: Thankyou, I get this error:Cannot assign to non-existent default property
                    MouseArea {
                    ^) 
QmlDocument:createRootNode document is not loaded or has errors, can't create root

Comment: What I am saying is that the Blackberry App can Not even start when MouseArea is used, and it shows that error message.

Comment: I don't know about Blackberry port of Qt. If I get to know I will sure let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
onTouch: {
  if (event.isUp()) {
    //do stuff here
  }
}
```